# Index route with hardcoded data

Tags: vue-router

I've been searching for index routes in the vue-router docs, but couldn't find how to do this:

I have

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/:slug', component: Project }
];
```

What I want is to specify a hardcoded slug for "/" (root), and to use the Project component for this path as well. Something like (this is wrong):

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', {'slug':'home-project'}, component:Project})
    { path: '/:slug', component: Project }
];
```

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, that was easy

```
const routes = [
    { path: '/', component: Project }
    { path: '/:slug', component: Project }
];
```

then in Project:

```
let slug = this.$route.params.slug;
if (!slug) {
    slug = 'some-default-slug';
}
```